# Set time used by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server database runs on a virtual dedicated server where it is not possible to adjust the time or timezone. Is it possible to force SQL Server to compensate for the system time by indicating either a timezone or by adding/subtracting hours so that any queries that get executed using fields that are datetime will use that time instead of the system time?

Comment: Why not store data in UTC, which works using e.g. GETUTCDATE() regardless of the server's time zone, and then adjust user-entered values on the client before running queries?

Comment: It would be nice to avoid depending on client settings. The server is dediated to providing data to a very specific geographical region.

Comment: By "client" I meant web server or application server, not end user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function like below and add/subtract time based upon your region

```
CREATE function [dbo].[sysdate]()
returns datetime
as
begin

declare @CurrentDate as datetime

select @CurrentDate = dateadd(minute, 330,GETUTCDATE());
return @CurrentDate;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to create a function timeOffset(yourzone)
according to the parameter, +1 for Germany for e.g.(how about the Summer Time!you have to work more on it) +8 for China etc
and dateadd(hour,getdate(),offset)

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetimeoffset to store your datetime values. it allows you to add timezone information to your data. for further details refer to the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx